# Does Backbone.js Model defaults override null, undefined, etc. I put in the View?

Tags: backbone.js, overriding, default-value

I'm making my first steps on `Backbone.js` and I'm having some problem on understanding how default values are set if the View get `undefined` or `null` values from outside:

```
var Status = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Templates:{}
}
Status.Models.Message = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        icon:'path/info-icon.png',
        type:'warning',
        title:'Information',
        message:'There is nothing to read here.'
    },
    initialize:function () {
        console.log("Status.Models.Message initialized");
    }
});

Status.Views.Message = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function () {
        console.log("Status.Views.Message initialized");
    },
    render:function () {
        var template = _.template($('#status-message-template').html());
        $('body').append($(this.el).attr('id', 'status-message').html(template(this.model.toJSON())));
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {$('#status-message').addClass('enter')}, 1500);

    }
});
```

I would like to find a way to let `Backbone.js` **overrides** `data` params and force it to use the `defaults` values in the case they are `""`, `undefined` or `null`.

```
$(function(){
    var data = {
       type:undefined,
       message:'This is the new message!'
    };
    var messageModel = new Status.Models.Message ();

    messageModel.set({
        type: data.type, // how to let it get defaults.type because data.type is undefined?
        message: data.message
    });

    var messageView = new Status.Views.Message({
        model:messageModel
    });
    messageView.render();
});
```

Does exists a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually mean, how to get the default value in case data.type is undefined?

you would need to define a default value, and then assign the one that is not undefined.
by doing a data.type || data.type_default, automatically returns the one not being undefined.

```
var data = {
 type : undefined,
 default_type : "something",
 ...
}

messageModel.set({
 type: data.type || data.default_type,
 ...
});
```